# Need a sufficiently long & complex Markdown document for performance testing

Tags: performance, testing, markdown

I'm looking for a long and complex Markdown document that I can use to test performance of different markdown implementations -- as an alternative to iterative benchmarking of a simple document.

I thought I might be able to browse around Stack Overflow and find something, but by and large everything I find is pretty simply written; and so far I'm not finding anything useful on Google.

Is there an existing document that showcases most or all Markdown syntax, perhaps written for just such a test?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try [this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.text) out. It's the source markdown of John Gruber's [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) page.

Be aware that there is some HTML in there as well.

In fact, nearly all pages on [John Gruber's site](http://daringfireball.net/) give you markdown if you append `.text` to the URL.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Should nesting formats (i.e. bold inside italic inside link text) affect performance?

Comment: Ask it as another question, don't ask me. I'm no markdown expert - I just happened to be setting it up on my blog yesterday!

Comment: Also, it probably depends on the implementation (going back to Joel and Jeff's regex vs. state machine discussion). Have a look at your implementation source and see how it deals with nesting.

Comment: Nested structures (quotes/apostrophes, bold, emph) can DEFINITELY affect performance.  When testing MultiMarkdown, one user kept complaining that the new/faster version was too slow.  Finally figured out he was writing in French, which involved many more single apostrophe characters which was causing enormous performance hits (multiple orders of magnitude).  My test suites for MultiMarkdown have several items in them for just this reason (e.g. the Edge Case test).

Answer (score 32):

Have you looked at/used [John Gruber's test suite](http://daringfireball.net/projects/downloads/MarkdownTest_1.0.zip)?

Comment: I find a full and downloadable test suite makes for a much better answer, giving my point here!

Answer (score 3):

After [Markdown Test Suite](https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite/) died when Commonmark came out of stealth mode (thus wasting large amounts of open source work time...), I forked the multi-implementation comparison part (mostly written by yours truly) at https://github.com/cirosantilli/commonmark-implementation-compare

The speed testing is naive, but gives an idea:

```
blackfriday     2.1222s  235  46%
cmark           1.9516s    1   0%
commonmarkjs   37.4651s    2   0%
hoedown         1.8875s  221  43%
kramdown       94.6460s  247  48%
markdown2      28.9707s  278  54%
markdown_pl    14.6919s  287  56%
markdownjs     40.3337s  302  59%
marked         35.3758s  258  50%
maruku         87.1664s  316  61%
multimarkdown   2.0579s  239  46%
pandoc          6.3442s  268  52%
peg_markdown    2.6402s  211  41%
rdiscount      42.0547s  200  39%
redcarpet      43.6608s  229  44%
showdown       45.0655s  285  55%
```

Likely the greatest flaw is that each tested input is fed from stdin, so interpreters are called each time, and suffer a large overhead.

**Original answer**

A possibility is using the Markdown Test Suite: https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite

Do `./cat-all.py` and then run your tests on `all.tmp.md`

It currently contains 103 tests, and already supports many markdown engines.

Simple benchmarks are already done for the total time of individual tests (also a meaningful parameter), and it would be really easy to implement it for the output of `cat-all.py`.